Async recursive scheduling in Rust
Using Tokio, how can I implement a system that, given a starting set of objects of type A, calls async process(a: A) -> Vec<A> on each of them and schedules everything it got back for recursive processing, while ensuring I only ever call process once for each A object?
I was thinking I could use something like tokio::sync::mpsc like in the following code (using i32 in place of A to simplify), but it doesn't work - I never enter the while loop.
use std::collections::HashSet;

use tokio::sync::mpsc;

async fn process(a: i32) -> Result<Vec<i32>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    Ok(vec![1])
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(32);
    let mut seen = HashSet::new();

    println!("Sending initial values");
    for n in vec![4, 5, 6] {
        tx.send(n).await.unwrap();
    }

    while let Some(n) = rx.recv().await {
        println!("Processing {}", n);
        if seen.insert(n) {
            let tx_clone = tx.clone();

            tokio::spawn(async move {
                println!("Start {}", n);
                let transitive
                    = process(n).await.unwrap();

                for n in transitive {
                    println!("Scheduling {}", n);
                    tx_clone.send(n).await.unwrap();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}


While sending each n in the vector, you don't await.
Should look something like:
println!("Sending initial values");
for n in vec![4, 5, 6] {
    tx.send(n).await.unwrap();
}


As it is in your code, we just have a pending future for each of the values in the vector that are never awaited.

It works better (although why does it matter that I want for the send to complete, as long as I eventually monitor the receiver stream?), however the program then never ends - it hangs after 1 got processed.

@MaëlNison "why does it matter that I want for the send to complete" - you don't await a future, it simply never runs.

@MaëlNison a future is basically a promise that we make to rust that we will call the method. Every async function returns this.
To actually run the async function(and fulfil our promise), we call .await. What will happen is until this is called is we will have promised rust to run this async at some point and never run it. That is what you did at tx.send(n).

@MaëlNison "it hangs" - worked for me in the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cb036f33e8df154dd7d84507282de3cb

@SergioTulentsev it hangs in the playground as well; if you add a println right after the while loop, it will never be executed. I suspect it's because tx is still open, but I had to leave open so it could be cloned to scheduled transitive tasks.

@MaëlNison would you consider running the while loop as it's own task. I believe that way, we should be able to get the print statement being run after the while loop.

@was1209 Do you have an example? As far as I can tell, moving the while loop inside its own task still prevents it from ending, which prevents the main from ending as well.

I updated the original code example to include the .await on the send call - resolving the hang is the primary objective, so the .await alone helps but isn't a full solution.

The problem is as you have realized that tx is always open and prevents rx.recv().await to return an error. This can be solved by checking right before tx_clone is dropped if the strong count of it is less than or equal to 2 and in that case send through a channel that it's time to terminate: (playground)
use std::collections::HashSet;

use tokio::sync::mpsc;

async fn process(a: i32) -> Result<Vec<i32>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    Ok(vec![1])
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(32);
    let (stopsend, mut stopreceive) = mpsc::channel(1);
    let mut seen = HashSet::new();

    println!("Sending initial values");
    for n in vec![4, 5, 6] {
        tx.send(n).await.unwrap();
    }
    
    loop {
        let Some(n) = tokio::select!(a = rx.recv() => a, stop = stopreceive.recv() => break) else {break;};
        println!("Processing {}", n);
        if seen.insert(n) {
            let tx_clone = tx.clone();
            let stopsendclone = stopsend.clone();

            tokio::spawn(async move {
                println!("Start {}", n);
                let transitive
                    = process(n).await.unwrap();

                for n in transitive {
                    println!("Scheduling {}", n);
                    tx_clone.send(n).await.unwrap();
                }
                if tx_clone.strong_count() <= 2 {
                    stopsendclone.send(()).await.unwrap();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}

Note that it doesn't work to simply check if the strong count is less than or equal to 1 in the end of the while let loop. That's because that check may happen before the last channel gets dropped.
