How can I close a Tokio mpsc channel on the sender side with multiple senders?
I am building a simple crawler, the idea was to spawn a new task every time a new URL is found and return all the links found in the page via mspc channel, but I ended up in a standstill.
The core of the issue is I need to close the channel from the sender side, but I am left with a copy of the sernder that I can't drop.
This is a simplified version to highlight the issue:
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

async fn visit_page(url: u32) -> Option<u32>{
    if url < 10 {
        Some (url + 1) 
    } else {
        None
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(100);
    
    tx.send(Some(0)).await.unwrap();

    while let Some(recv) = rx.recv().await {
        if let Some(url) = recv {
            println!("Got = {}", url);
            let tx = tx.clone();
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                tx.send(visit_page(url).await).await.unwrap();
            });
        }
    }
}

link to playground
Since tx is hanging around, the channel stays open and rx.recv().await will never return even after the final task has completed.
I've spent some time experimenting with WeakSender with no success.

One option that allows you to keep this code structure is to send the sender back through the channel, which allows you to drop tx held by the main loop. This requires a newtype to avoid an infinitely-recursing Sender type. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8c3b1bcbe6ae7107a5fbc197605e7218 There is probably a better way, though.

I believe the problem here is the same as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78289260/async-recursive-scheduling-in-rust/
